# Trigger on OLI update seems to fire twice

Tags: trigger, update

I am trying to send an email notification if an opportunitylineitem field has changed.
For this i created a trigger and it works well BUT it sends 2 emails and i don't understand why. Obviously one is enough :-)
( i also tried to add a system debug and i see it twice too. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger OLIsendEmail on OpportunityLineItem (before Update) {
   private static final String NOTIFICATION_MAIL_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE = ' {0}: A product field__c has changed';
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    List<String> NOTIFICATION_EMAILS =new String[] {'myemail@here.com'};
    for( Id OpportunityLineItemId : Trigger.newMap.keySet() ){
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get( OpportunityLineItemId ).status__c=='XYZ'){   
            if( Trigger.oldMap.get( OpportunityLineItemId ).field__c != Trigger.newMap.get( OpportunityLineItemId ).field__c ){  
                mail.setToAddresses(NOTIFICATION_EMAILS);
                mail.setSubject(
                    String.format(
                        NOTIFICATION_MAIL_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE,
                        new String[] {
                            String.valueOf('hello')
                        }
                    )
                );             
                String emailBody = 'Some Email body!';
                mail.setHtmlBody(emailBody);            
                emailsToSend.add(mail);                   
            }
        }
    } //End For
    if (!emailsToSend.isEmpty()) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToSend);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check to see if you have any Flows, Process Builders, Workflow Rules, or other triggers that perform a recursive update. This would be the most likely reason why you'd see this behavior. You'll need the read the entire debug log, not just the debug statements, to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - as always-, I'll go and check all of this and try again .!